# Diesel car struggles to start when cold

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, diesel, glowplugs, starter

Recently had the timing belt, water pump, all valves and rocker arms, fuel filter, oil filter, air filter changed on my 2006 Audi A3 8P 2.0 TDI 140.

I've had it back for two days now and it struggles to start when cold. Splutters a little when started warm but generally starts pretty quick. Any idea why?

My initial thoughts are glow plugs or starter motor…

Comment: What make/model/year is the vehicle in question?

Comment: Audi A3 8P 2006 2.0 TDI 140

Comment: It probably has some residual air in the line. I'm not sure how you'd go about bleeding these, though. If you are having issues with how it runs, I'd suggest taking it back to the shop where you had the work done and get them to get it running correctly. That is what you paid them for, I'd suspect.

Comment: Yep, the cambelt became loose and took out valves and rocker arms because the cylinder head stud came off which is common on these engines apparently. It wouldn't start at all and was an extensive repair. I've got a slight concern that if I take it back, they're gonna say it's a starter motor or glowplug, or injector repair and try to bill me for it....

Comment: Does it run OK once started? It sounds like glow plugs to me, and a quick diagnostics test should reveal which one(s) are faulty.

Comment: Yeah, runs fine as soon as its started up. Hmm, will get my friend to run a diagnostics on it then!

Comment: If it only happens when it's cold then do check the glowplugs, they eventually fail no matter what the engine is. They should receive power for a few seconds when you turn to ignition. You should actually see them glow orange/yellow if you pull them out, just don't burn your face.

Comment: What do you mean by "cold?" I wouldn't expect you to need the glow plugs to get this engine running smoothly unless the weather was colder than 10º C (50º F). I think that engine will set codes if it is having glow plug problems.

Comment: If you haven't resolved the problem, it would be worth having the timing checked. For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure that engine doesn't have rocker  arms. More likely that the cam followers (lifters, why do they call them lifters when they are used to push down?) were replaced.

Comment: No follow up by OP since 18 June.

Comment: Additional possibility: the battery could be becoming old, not turning the starter motor with enough many amperes.